# Why does fixed positioning alter the width of an element?

Tags: css, position

I have a `<div>` that has its width set as `100%`. When I add `position:fixed` to it, the width becomes `16px` larger.

I noticed that on the body, there are `8px` margins on all sides, so I am guessing that `position:fixed` is somehow ignoring the margins of the body tag in which it is contained.

I looked at the [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position) but was unable to find anything that explains what is going on.

**What has `position:fixed` changed about the `<div>` that causes this behavior?**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UpeXV/

Comment: wild guess: You're no longer dealing with the `body`'s padding so `width:100%` is probably using the window width now.

Comment: Sounds like the expected behaviour? It's spreading out to 100% of the document's width.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm not saying that it isn't the expected behavior, I am just trying to understand *why* it is happening

Comment: @BradChristie Perhaps, but `body` has `margin` and no padding.

Comment: @ChrisB: Well, i guess I'm saying the 8px spacing between `<body>` and the next child element is half the width difference in the two elements. I should probably interject and say I'm not a UI guy. I hate doing UI and dealing with CSS/layouts, but if I were a gambling man that'd be what I'd bet on. `fixed` it making it use window sizing instead of `body`, thus the width change.

Comment: @BradChristie Thanks for the input man, that was spot on.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `body` automatically has a margin of `8px`.  So when you set the `width` of your element to `100%`, it becomes the width of the body, less `8px` on both sides.

But when you give the element `position:fixed`, it no longer is set relative to the body but to the viewport, which doesn't have margins.  So the `width` is now the width of the viewport, which is 2 * `8px` wider - the `16px` that you observe.

Here's the [W3 documentation on the subject](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Fixed_positioning):

> Whereas the position and dimensions of an element with position:absolute are relative to its containing block, the position and dimensions of an element with position:fixed are always relative to the initial containing block. This is normally the viewport: the browser window or the paper’s page box.

Comment: This helps me understand what exactly is going on when position changes in CSS thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

If you need the fixed element to be 100% width, and you still want space, you can consider using `box-sizing: border-box`. Then use padding, rather than margins, to create space. This will allow the fixed element to span the width of the page without going over. Margins and borders and padding are always added to the dimensions of an element, unless you use the `border-box` model, in which case width will include padding and borders.

See: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when you set an element to `position:fixed`, it takes on the width of the viewport instead of its parent.

> Fixed positioning is similar to absolute positioning, with the exception that the element's containing block is the viewport.

[MDN CSS Position Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position)

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior for fixed elements, since a fixed element does not orientate itself in context to its closest positioned parent but the viewport, thus getting fixed in the window. The 16px more width come from the fact, as you pointed out yourself, that the body has a default margin of 8px.