# Bootstrap fixed div (width increase to 100%)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap 3 and I like to create my fixed header. The problem is when the fixed header get fixed the header increase to a width 100%.

I have put my problem into an example:

http://www.bootply.com/MTi0Nr1N9s

Here is a screen what happens:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a75pjah7a

Does anybody has an idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the normal behaviour of `position:fixed`:

> The position and dimensions of an element with position:fixed are always relative to the initial containing block. This is normally the viewport: the browser window or the paper’s page box.

Source: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16442617/4334348)

To overcome this problem, you have to fix the width of container (example: `width: 1170px`) and changing the width of the header to inherit instead of 100%.

Comment: Is there any way to do this and keeping the site responsive?

Comment: I am afraid there isn't, but you can try to use navbar-fixed-top class of bootstrap to try to overcome this problem